# Integrate class attributes in client namespace

Tags: python, python-import, python-dataclasses

I want to define a bunch of attributes for use in a module that should also be accessible from other modules, because they're part of my interface contract.

I've put them in a data class in my module like this, but I want to avoid qualifying them every time, similar to how you use `import *` from a module:

```
@dataclass
class Schema:
    key1='key1'
    key2='key2'
```

and in the same module:

```
<mymodule.py>

print(my_dict[Schema.key1])
```

I would prefer to be able to do this:

```
print(my_dict[key1])
```

I was hoping for an equivalent syntax to:

```
from Schema import *
```

This would allow me to do this from other modules too:

```
<another_module.py>
from mymodule.Schema import *
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So why don't You create a package and then the Schema will be realy an module so You will be able to do this

Comment: I would prefer to keep the dataclass tightly coupled with `mymodule` because that's the module that defines this contract.

Comment: I dont recomend this but You can do something like this `locals().update(mymodule.Schema.__dict__)`

Comment: Why do you put those key value pairs into a class? You can just write them into the module as constants, since that's how you use them anyway.

Comment: @Arne, I thought that might allow me to export them as a unit to other modules, but of course that didn't work, so I'm not tied to a class. If I just wrote them as constants though, how could I package them for use by other modules in a way that doesn't require qualification?

Comment: The module (which is in the context of this problem a single file) is the interface for importing, so you can use that. You can dedicate one file for constants, I usually have one `settings.py` on the top level of my projects that will contain a bunch of things that are valuable for sharing within it, like `VERSION = '0.1.0'` or `TARGET_URL = 'http://some/address.com'`, things that are not expected to change during runtime. If your scenario is similar, then you can use that and should be fine. Module constants only get tricky if they are mutated.

Comment: @Arne, I'm tending towards this now. I was hoping there was some magical `from mymodule.mydataclass import *` that I didn't know about, but the answer seems to be no there isn't. Having a separate file for those constants seems to be the only practical solution. If you'd like to type it out as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Steven sure, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short glossary

**module** - a python file that can be imported

**package** - a collection of modules in a directory that can also be imported, is technically also a module

**name** - shorthand for a [named value](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) (often just "variable" in other languages), they can be imported from modules

---

Using `import` statements allows you to import either packages, modules, or names:

```py
import xml                                                     # package
from xml import etree                                          # also a package
from xml.etree import ElementTree                              # module
from xml.etree.ElementTree import TreeBuilder                  # name
# --- here is where it ends ---
from xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder import element_factory  # does not work
```

The dots in such an import chain can only be made after [module objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), which packages and modules are, and names are not. So, while it looks like we are just accessing attributes of objects, we are actually relying on a mechanism that normal objects just don't support, so we can't import from within them.

In your particular case, a reasonable solution would be to simply turn the object that you wanted to hold the schema into a top-level module in your project:

**schema.py**

```py
key1 = 'key1'
key2 = 'key2'
...
```

Which will give you the option to import them in the way that you initially proposed. Doing something like this to make common constants easily accessible in your project is not unusual, and the django framework for example uses a `settings.py` in the same manner.

One thing you should keep in mind is that names in python modules are effectively [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), so their values can't be changed at runtime<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>They can, but it's so hacky that it should pretty much always be treated as not possible.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks @Arne, I agree this is the way to do it.